# How to cache stored procedure results to retrieve the results faster?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes a lot of time (around 5 minutes) to execute. This stored procedure fills up a table. Now I am retrieving the data from that table. I have created a job to execute this stored procedure every 15 minutes. But while the stored procedure is in execution, my table is empty and the front end shows no results at that time. My requirement is to show data at the front end side all the time.

Is there a way to cache the stored procedure results and use that result while the stored procedure executes?

Here is my stored procedure,

```
BEGIN
declare @day datetime
declare @maxdate datetime
set @maxdate = getdate()
set @day = Convert(Varchar(10),DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0),110)
truncate table tblOpenTicketsPerDay
while  @day <= @maxdate
begin
insert into tblOpenTicketsPerDay
select convert(varchar(20),datename(dw,@day)) day_name, count(*) Open_Tickets from 
(select [status], createdate, closedate 
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DSN=SQLite','Select * from tickets') AS a
where createdate <= @day
except
select [status], createdate, closedate 
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DSN=SQLite','Select * from tickets') AS a
where closedate <= @day and [status] = 'closed') x
set @day = @day + 1
end
END
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correct then your main concern is: your stored procedure empties the table and then fills it up and since it takes time, your application have no data show.

In that case, you can have a secondary/auxiliary clone table; say `tblOpenTicketsPerDay_clone` and have your stored procedure fill that table instead like

```
insert into tblOpenTicketsPerDay_clone
select convert(varchar(20),datename(dw,@day)) day_name, 
count(*) Open_Tickets from
```

That way your application will always have data to display since main table has the data. Once, the clone table is done filling up then transfer the same data to main table saying

```
delete from tblOpenTicketsPerDay;

insert into tblOpenTicketsPerDay
select * from tblOpenTicketsPerDay_clone;
```

Comment: But the 2nd insert query will add same rows again next time it executes. Also, update will only update the existing rows but will not edit them.

Comment: @Arpita, see edit again; I mean to say .. delete rows from main table and then insert.

Comment: You can use a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement instead of a `DELETE` on your data table (if your table supports it) this is much quicker than a delete for various reasons

Answer (score 1):

No, but the problem is not caching, it isa totally bad approach to generate the data.

Generate new data into a temporary table, then MERGE The results (using the merge keyword) into the original table.

No sense in deleting the data first. That is a terrible design approach.